# How to add C++ code into ROS package

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am properly executing the moveit_tutorial for the move_group_interface example at [Move Group C++ Interface](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html)

The example code is in just one file, [move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/doc/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp). Is launched as

```
ros@ros-VirtualBox:~$ roslaunch moveit_tutorials move_group_interface_tutorial.launch
```

Then, I would like to create a cpp file in order to perform some coding. To test if it will be properly compiled, I just copy the example file and renamed it to test.cpp in the same folder. Then, I perform catkin_make after adding this line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(moveit_tutorials doc/move_group_interface/src/test.cpp)
```

However, I am getting errors because of undefined references:

```
[ 74%] Building CXX object moveit_tutorials/CMakeFiles/moveit_tutorials.dir/doc/move_group_interface/src/test.cpp.o

[ 75%] Linking CXX executable moveit_tutorials CMakeFiles/moveit_tutorials.dir/doc/move_group_interface/src/test.cpp.o: In function main': test.cpp:(.text+0x46c): undefined reference toros::init(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
```

I am quite new in ROS and, in general, I would like to know how should I add a C++ code into an existing node package, following with the example.

What should I do to compile and rosrun the code instead of the roslaunch done in the example. Or the proper approach to do a launch file. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334620/how-to-add-c++-code-into-ros-package/) by [UR5e](https://answers.ros.org/users/46501/ur5e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not linking your binary anything, so there are references that are not found. Somthing like this is missing:

```
target_link_libraries(moveit_tutorials ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Here is more info: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#target_link_libraries

---

Originally posted by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) with karma: 128 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UR5e](https://answers.ros.org/users/46501/ur5e/) on 2019-10-04**:
I already tried but the error is the same:

```
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable moveit_tutorials
CMakeFiles/moveit_tutorials.dir/doc/move_group_interface/src/test.cpp.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x46c): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
```

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2019-10-04**:
If you included the target_link_libraries and it still doesn't work, you can try the solutions described in: https://answers.ros.org/question/291910/linking-problem-with-catkin_libraries/